# Tasks with parents showing up under Unparented in TFS 2015

Tags: tfs-2015

After upgrading to TFS 2015 I have a bunch of tasks showing up under Unparented in the Backlog for the current iteration. These tasks all have parents though. Going through each task it looks like the parents are all User Stories in Active or Removed states. Resolved User Stories are showing up with their Tasks just fine. How can I get Active and Resolved User Stories to show up in the backlog with their tasks?

Comment: See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ddf7f442-02d1-47c7-a35f-87147bfe120c/unparented-bug-in-tfs-online?forum=tfsgeneral   There you can see that "sometimes" the "link type" is not a "Parent/Child"  as expected ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I had to edit my process configuration and add Active, Removed and a few other states to the `<States>` of the `<RequirementBacklog>` section.

Used:

```
witadmin exportprocessconfig ...
```

to export the config, edited it in notepad the

```
witadmin importprocessconfig
```

to import the update config

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500413.aspx) for more

Answer (score 0):

> You can track unparented tasks in similar ways to other tasks, or **drag
> them to an existing backlog item to parent them**. The Unparented card
> tracks the total of remaining work defined for all unparented tasks,
> however, it isn’t associated with any work item.
>
> source: [Task board from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/work/scrum/task-board)

Comment: These tasks aren't actually unparented

Answer (score 0):

We show the parent User Stories if they satisfy these rules:

- it needs to be New, Active, Resolved or Closed. We don't show Removed User Stories
- it needs to be in an area path that is used by the team.

My suspicion is that the second requirement is not true. There is also a button on the toolbar that says "Create Query" that gives you the query we use to get the data for the task board for further debugging if needed.

Comment: You forgot the "Approved" state. Even so, the PBI shown as "Unparented". Seems to be a bug depending how the PBI/tasks were created.

Comment: ... there is definitively a bug in the current TFS Online version regarding to the "Unparented" issue!

Comment: The states I listed were for the Agile process, while the Approved state would as well as the Committed state would be the states for the Scrum process. I would like to know more what you are experiencing. Feel free to reach out to me at ehofman at Microsoft dot com to get this investigated.

Comment: Open PBI, click "+" to add a task, result: Unparented